# Formula for the $n^{th}$ derivative of $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am presented the following prompt:

Find a formula for the $n^{th}$ derivative of $f(x) = \frac{x^n}{1-x}$

I've split the function into two parts to differentiate at the suggestion of some users (I originally checked a series of $n$ derivatives to find a pattern).

$f(x) = \dfrac{x^n}{1-x} = \dfrac{1}{1-x} - \dfrac{1-x^n}{1-x}$

I find the formula for the $n^{th}$ derivative of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ to be $\frac{n!}{(1-x)^{n+1}}$ because $\frac{d}{dx} [\frac{c}{(1-x)^k}] = \frac{kc}{(1-x)^{k+1}}$ where $c$ is a constant.

This would mean that the derivative of $\dfrac{1-x^n}{1-x}$ must be $0$.

I don't understand how this would be determined.

Comment: I don't think you computed your derivatives correctly.

Comment: @nayrb based on what?

Comment: But still, what you are looking for is the $n$th derivative. $n$ is assumed fixed, so it doesn't do you much to set values for $n$. What you should do is deal with $f(x)$ as it is, and compute the $k$th derivative for $k = 1,2,\cdots$ and look for a pattern.

Comment: @Ahmed The formula for the $n^{th}$ derivative of the function $f(x)$ is what I've given, unless you dispute it. $n$ is variable. As $n$ varies, so does the degree of the derivative. When $n = 5$ you are taking the $5^{th}$ derivative.

Comment: $n$ isn't variable. It can't be. To define $f(x)$, you should have $n$ fixed first. $n$ is variable in the sense that we are not assigning a numerical value to it, yes. But not variable in the precise sense of the word. Anyway, the formula is not correct. Obviously, there is something wrong with the denominator's power, and the numerator doesn't look right; besides, I checked it for $n = 1$ and $n = 2$.

Comment: It's actually a reasonable question, and there is a reason why you would want to look at the $n$th derivative of $\frac{x^n}{1-x}$ rather than at any lower (or higher) derivative. Sometimes it _does_ make sense to use the same variable in places where you technically could have two different variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a pattern here to recognise:

$$\frac{x^n}{1-x} = \frac{1 - (1-x^n)}{1-x} = \frac{1}{1-x} - \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}.$$

The derivatives of the first summand, if one hasn't memorised them, are easily found by differentiating a few times, spotting a pattern, and proving it via induction. The second summand should be familiar as the closed form for a geometric sum.

> This would mean that the derivative of $\dfrac{1-x^n}{1-x}$ must be $0$.

The $n^{\text{th}}$ derivative of that must be $0$, not necessarily the lower order derivatives. And indeed, $\dfrac{1-x^n}{1-x}$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$ [for $n > 0$], so its $n^{\text{th}}$ derivative is $0$. Starting with a geometric sum $1 + x + \dotsc + x^{n-1}$, multiplying with $1-x$ yields

$$(1-x)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^{k+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k - \sum_{m=1}^n x^m = 1 - x^n.$$

For $x\neq 1$, we can divide by $1-x$ and obtain

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k = \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}.$$

In that form, the derivatives are easily computed if required, but we know that the $n^{\text{th}}$ derivative of a polynomial of degree $< n$ is $0$ without computation.

Comment: I mistyped it. I have the right result. It was just going about finding it that I was questioning. It seems like there might be a simpler way to find the pattern or the formula without having to compute enough derivatives to see that the top is $n!$

Comment: Well, for $\frac{1}{1-x}$, you either remember the derivatives (they're easy enough, after working with them a couple of times, you remember them without conscious effort), or you have to compute them far enough to spot the pattern. The polynomial is of degree $n-1$, so you know the $n^{\text{th}}$ derivative of that is $0$. Doing the split here certainly leads to a much simpler computation than computing the first $n$ derivatives of $\frac{x^n}{1-x}$ with the chain rule already for fairly small $n$.

Comment: I'm familiar with the first summand, and it truly is fairly simple to derive even if I weren't. However, I'm not familiar with the second summand. Do you know a good place to read up on its form?

Comment: Would $\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$ imply $\frac{x^0-x^n}{1-x}$?

Comment: @Alex For $x \neq 1$, we have $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k = \frac{1-x^n}{1-x},$$ that is the closed formula for a geometric sum. You can prove that by multiplying both sides with $1-x$ for example. So $\frac{1-x^n}{1-x} = 1 + x + \dotsc + x^{n-1}$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$. Hence the $n^{\text{th}}$ derivative of that is $0$ - the lower order derivatives don't vanish (identically).